# Why is my Polymer custom CSS property not working?

Tags: css, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm taking my first steps in Polymer, and I'm stuck on custom CSS properties.

In `my-item` element, I am checking for the `--my-item-color` variable and assigning `red` as a default value:

```
<dom-module id="my-item">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .my-div {
        background-color: var(--my-item-color, red);
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="my-div">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({ is: "my-item" });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

These items are in the following container element, but somehow all `my-item`s remain red.

```
<dom-module id="my-container">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --my-item-color: blue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    </style>
    <content></content>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({ is: "my-container" });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LovSp4VRAGpLadcr87Wz

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [native CSS properties from Polymer 1.6.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/release-notes#v-1-6-0) to allow your current code to work. Make sure to enable it by setting up your `Polymer` object's `useNativeCSSProperties` property before importing `polymer.html`:

```
<script>
  Polymer = {
    lazyRegister: true,
    useNativeCSSProperties: true
  };
</script>
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../x-element.html">
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xmt3MWRfr1dWbiEPBZ78?p=preview)

Comment: this fixes the issue, still wondering why it isn't supported in polymer itself tho

Comment: @AdrianoSpadoni It also works in Shadow DOM ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ffEfQhJfRvAorw7YKbbh?p=preview)).

Comment: @tony19 it was failing in a really edge case, one component (I did not write) add an element to the body when in shadow dom, the css will not be considered because now it is out off the shadow... the issue was in the 3rd party component. My comment was write before I found the issue. You are right, it works on shadow dom.